# Convolutional Neural Network : Weights and Bias initialization

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I'm building convolutional neural network for classification of the data into different categories
The input data is of shape : 30000, 6, 15, 1
the data has 30000 samples, 15 predictors and 6 possible categories.

My model is defined as follows.

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 6,15,1])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

#Define Weights
weights = {
    'wc1': tf.get_variable('W0', shape=(3,3,1,8), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wc2': tf.get_variable('W1', shape=(3,3,32,12), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wc3': tf.get_variable('W2', shape=(3,3,64,16), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wc4': tf.get_variable('W3', shape=(3,3,64,20), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'wd1': tf.get_variable('W4', shape=(4*4*15,15), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'out': tf.get_variable('W6', shape=(15,n_classes), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
}

biases = {
    'bc1': tf.get_variable('B0', shape=(8), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bc2': tf.get_variable('B1', shape=(12), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bc3': tf.get_variable('B2', shape=(16), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bc4': tf.get_variable('B3', shape=(20), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bd1': tf.get_variable('B4', shape=(15), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'out': tf.get_variable('B5', shape=(6), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
}

#Define convolutional layer
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1, reuse=True):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

#Define Maxpool layer
def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],padding='SAME')

#Define a convolutional neural network function
def conv_net(x, weights, biases):  
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    conv3 = conv2d(conv2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])
    conv3 = maxpool2d(conv3, k=2)

    conv4 = conv2d(conv3, weights['wc4'], biases['bc4'])
    conv4 = maxpool2d(conv4, k=2)


    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv4, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    # Output, class prediction 
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return out
```

I'm getting the error : `ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 8 and 32 for 'Conv2D_1' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,8,3,8], [3,3,32,12].`

When I execute :

```
pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases)
```

I went through multiple conv2D models but most of them are for image classification and I might be missing something here that I'm not able to identify. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of input channels for the weights `wc2`, `wc3`, and `wc4` need to be the same as the number of output channels for the previous layers.  Keeping the number of output channels the way you have it, they would be changed to:

```
    'wc1': tf.get_variable('W0', shape=(3,3,1,8), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'wc2': tf.get_variable('W1', shape=(3,3,8,12), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'wc3': tf.get_variable('W2', shape=(3,3,12,16), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'wc4': tf.get_variable('W3', shape=(3,3,16,20), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
```